# Is the problem of Proper Subset of decidable languages decidable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability, halting-problem

Given 2 recursive - decidable languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ is the problem $L_1 \subset L_2$ solvable - decidable?

Since both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are recursive - decidable there exist Turing Machines say $M_1$ and $M_2$ that decide them.

Say that the problem stated is decidable then there exists a Turing Machine $M_3$ that given two deciders $M_i$ and $M_j$ responds with **YES** if $L(M_i) \subset
 L(M_j)$ otherwise it responds with **NO**.

If $M_3$ actually exists then there exists a Turing machine say $M_4$ that decides the Halting Problem and works in the following way:

- Given $\langle M,w\rangle$ it constructs the description  of a Turing Machine $M^*$ that given any input $x$ it erases $x$ from its tape, then writes $w$ on it and simulates $M$ on $w$. If $M$ halts on $w$ then $M^*$ responds with **YES** and $L(M^*) = Σ^*$ otherwise it loops infinitely as $M$ loops on $w$ and $L(M^*) = \emptyset$.
- Then it constructs the description of a Turing Machine say $M^o$ such that $L(M^o) = Σ^*$
- Next step is to feed $\langle M^*,M^o\rangle$ to $M_3$:

  - If $M_3$ responds with **YES** then $L(M^*) \subset L(M^o)$ so $M$ does not halt on $w$ and $M_4$ responds with **NO**.
  - If $M_3$ responds with **NO** then $L(M^*) \not\subset L(M^o)$ so $M$ halts on $w$ and $M_4$ responds with **YES**.

This is how I approached the problem but my concern is that the way $M^*$ works does not make it a decider as it may loop forever. Is there any way that I can modify my approach and make it work?

Comment: The exercise "given $2$ decidable languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ is the problem $L_1 \subset L_2$ decidable?" could be interpreted as "given $2$ decidable language $L_1$ and $L_2$, is there an algorithm which responds with YES if $L_1\subset L_2$ and which responds with NO if $L_1\not\subset L_2$?". The answer is true, since either the algorithm that says YES or the algorithm that says NO satisfies the requirement. Similarly, the answer to "given any number $n$, is there a number greater than $n$?" is YES, although the answer to "is there a number which is greater than any given number?" is NO.

Comment: On the other hand, the exercise can be interpreted as "is the language $\{\langle M_1, M_2\rangle\mid M_1, M_2 \text{ are deciders}, L(M_1)\subset L(M_2)\}$ decidable?". This interpretation presents The problem this post and my answer try to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a modification of your approach that works.

The idea is to construct language $L_1$ so that it is not empty if and only if the given $M$ halts on the given $w$. Then use $M_3$ to check whether $L_1$ is empty.

As in the question, a Turing machine responds with **YES** or **NO** means it accepts or rejects respectively. A language is decidable when a decider for it is given.   "$\subset$" means "is a proper subset of".

---

Let $D$ be a Turing machine that decides given decidable language $L_1$ and $L_2$ whether $L_1\subset L_2$.

Given $\langle M,w\rangle$, Turing machine $M_6$ will do the following.

1. It constructs Turing machine $H$ which on input $x$:

   1. Counts the number of symbols in $x$. Let it be $n$.
   2. Simulates $M$ on input $w$ up to $n$ steps. If the simulation halts within $n$ steps, accepts. Otherwise, rejects.

   Note that $H$ is a decider. $L(H)$ is empty iff $M$ does not halt on input $w$.
2. It feeds $\langle L(H), \{\epsilon\}\rangle$ to $D$. Note that $\{\epsilon\}$ is a decidable language.

   - If $D$ responds with **YES**, then $L(H) \subset L(E)$, which means $L(H)$ is empty, which means $M$ does not halt on $w$.
     It responds with **NO**.
   - If $D$ responds with **NO**, then $L(H) \not\subset L(E)$, which means $L(H)$ is not empty, which means $M$ halts on $w$.
     It responds with **YES**.

$M_6$ is a decider for the halting problem.

---

The approach above uses $D$ only to decide whether a given decidable language is empty or not. Hence, we have proved, in fact, it is undecidable whether a given decidable language is empty or not.

---

Here is an exercise, which is another stronger form of the exercise in the question.

Is it decidable whether $\{a^n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\subset L_2$ where $L_2$ is a decidable language $L_2$ over an alphabet that has $a$ and $b$?

Comment: What concerns me is the description of both $M^o$ and $M^h$ as they might loop forever. I am new to TM but as far as I know a decider must respond with YES or NO. An idea is to restate the hypothesis: Say that the problem is decidable then there exists a Turing Machine $M_3$ that given two Turing Machines $M_i$ and $M_j$ whose languages are decidable responds with YES if $L(M_i) \subset L(M_j)$ otherwise it responds with NO. Another idea is to try to prove that the $L(M_i) \subseteq L(M_j)$ is not provable since proper subset requires to prove that and the fact that $|L(M_i)| < |L(M_j)|$

Comment: @RookieCookie Thanks for pointing out my typo. I should have written "rejects" instead of "loops forever".

Comment: Would you mind providing some feedback on the other 2 approaches? Furthermore your solution  is so elegant but I want to make sure I understand correctly. The language of $M^o$ is always $Σ^* \setminus \{ε\}$ and the language of $M^h$ is either the ${ε}$ or the strings whose length $|x| \geq 1 $ if $M$ does not halt on $w$, right?

Comment: It looks you have understood my answer correctly.

Comment: One of the other 2 approaches of yours led me to a slightly-simpler solution. I will update answer to prove that it is undecidable whether a decidable language accepts at least one string, i.e., given a decider $M$, is $|L(M)|=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's way simpler now!

Comment: Thanks for your ideas.